# vncserver refuses to start

Tags: vnc, systemd

I have a Fedora 15 server that has been running just fine for months until I suffered a power outage. After the recovery, all services came back up just fine except `vncserver`. When I try to start the daemon with the following command:

```
# service vncserver start
```

I get the following:

```
Starting vncserver (via systemctl): Job failed. See system logs and 'systemctl status' for details. [FAILED]
```

I've looked in `/var/log/messages` and could not find the culprit. Doing a  `systemctl status vncserver.service` yields the following:

```
vncserver.service - LSB: start|stop|restart|try-restart|status|force-reload vncserver
Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/vncserver)
Active: failed since Mon, 23 Jan 2012 22:57:11; 1min 28s ago
Process: 4701 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/vncserver start (code=exited, status=126)
CGroup:name=systemd:/system/vncserver.service
```

Please keep in mind that the problem does not lie in the `vncservers`, `iptables`, or `xstartup` files as all of these were working perfectly before the outage; they have not changed, and I have exact duplicates of these files on another machine that run just fine as-is. Uninstalling and reinstalling from RPM does no good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to run it just like that ? : `/etc/rc.d/init.d/vncserver`

Comment: That's what it was! Thanks to your suggestion, I found a still-in-use but corrupt session in /tmp/.X11-unix/X15. Deleting the X15 file solved the issue. Thanx!

Comment: @Anthony There's a checkmark on the left you can click to accept this if it solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

```
Failed to start Remote desktop service (VNC).
```

or

```
Unit vncserver@:7.service entered failed state.
```

or

```
Job for vncserver@:7.service failed. See 'systemctl status vncserver@:7.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
```

Delete this folder:

```
rm -r /tmp/.X11-unix/
```

And reboot. Then check `tigervnc` is ok for run port configure .

Answer (score 0):

I changed `VNCSERVERS` to `VNCUSERS`, e.g.:

```
VNCUSERS="2:username"
VNCUSERARGS[2]="-geometry 1280x1024"
```

Then:

```
service iptables stop
service vncserver start
```

Now it works.